# jMeter "Prepared SELECT Statement" - does it substitute bind variables?

Tags: sql, jdbc, jmeter, hana

I am using jMeter to load test a SAP HANA database using a JDBC request that issues a SELECT statement using a "Prepared SELECT Statement" query type.

```
select * from accounts where acc = '${__P(acct),)} order by ts LIMIT 10
```

It is reading from a table with tens of billions of records, and I expect a throughput of several thousand transactions per second.
The "acct" is a unique PK that is read in from a CSV using a CSV Data Set Config, substituted using a BeanShell Listener.

The SQL statement in the database cache contains statements such as

```
select * from accounts where acc = 110982 order by ts LIMIT 10
```

This is a problem because the database has to parse each statement and it is a high CPU overhead. Using a "Prepared SELECT Statement" I had expect to see something like this:

```
select * from accounts where acc = :acc order by ts LIMIT 10
```

Where the statement is prepared and a value substituted at runtime, avoiding re-parsing.

The jMeter documentation is mute on the subject so does a JDBC query type of "Prepared SELECT Statement" substitute literals for bind variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Prepared Select Statement should look like the one mentioned in the screenshot attached from the apache Jmeter Documentation site:

http://jmeter.apache.org/images/screenshots/jdbctest/jdbc-request.png

The way you have written your prepared select statement is incorrect.

Also you can pass the variables from the CSV Data Set Config directly "${acct}", there is no need of passing them as properties  "__P(acct)"

Use below details as reference for your prepared select statement:

```
select * from accounts where acc = ?  order by ts LIMIT 10
```

**Parameter Value:** ${acct}
**Parameter Type:** *As per your DB Schema*

Hope this will Help.